# How to force Windows XP to use a particular driver?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, ahci

I understand in theory how to enable AHCI after having installed windows in IDE mode.

I am running into this problem however: the driver provided by Asus for Windows XP Pro x64, AMD AHCI Driver V3.2.1540.92, is not recognized by Windows XP Pro x64 (i.e. when I try to update my Primary IDE Channel or just install this driver using new hardware). I cannot install it at all (no selection of what's inside the file).

Question: **How do I install the AMD AHCI XP Pro x64 driver under Windows XP Pro x64?**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any suggestions? How can I force windows to use this driver? Is there some trick to this particular driver?

Thank you all.

P.S. I have an Asus Sabertooth AMD Motherboard and, of course, am running Windows XP Pro x64.

**If my question is not clear, please let me know, and I will clarify.**

Anyone? Anyone at all? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's how I got around the issue**

If your BIOS supports changing modes for certain ports (E.g. mine allowed me to set ports 1-4 ACHI and 5-6 IDE)

1. Put your HDD (with XP on it) on 5-6
2. Place a second drive (with at least one accessible partition) on 1-4
3. Reboot
4. Windows will ask you to install a driver for this unknown device. Try using the driver   you found or [this one that worked for me](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/6xa105ww.zip)
5. Reboot again, and if all went well you should be able to access that drive. Don't go any further/swap to ACHI for all drives if that didn't work.
6. Assuming that drive worked, now you can set all drives to ACHI, as windows is smart enough to copy that existing driver, even during the initial boot sequence.

***Don't have a second Drive? BIOS doesn't allow seperate controller modes?***

You can try simply replacing your **IDE controller** driver with the one I linked above. But note you have no way of knowing whether it will screw your computer up, so remember to backup your stuff. You will most likely be looking for ***Primary (or secondary) IDE controller***.

Comment: For the record, I would suggest you go to Windows 7 x64, XP x64 is not a pleasant experience at all :/ Luckily for you the driver I linked does include a x64 version, so have a try, but I really recommend that you upgrade- much easier to find drivers/solutions! Sorry for the lateness of my answer, hope it still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Did you go back and enable it in your BIOS? First do that, then, if you can even boot into Windows, try to install the driver.

By the way, all the good books say (and my own experience shows) that you needed to have set AHCI BEFORE installing Windows, and furthermore, driver support for Windows XP 64-bit is spotty at best.

Comment: Without installing the driver first, I cannot boot into Windows with AHCI enabled in BIOS.  I understand that in theory, it should have been set before installing Windows, but alas, that is not an option.  Furthermore, this should be possible and has been demonstrated to work by many people all over the web.  I just don't understand why the driver is not recognized! Argh! So frustrating! Thank you for the comment though :)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response; thank you for your comment / answer.  I will give it a try and get back to you :)